# IApplication in AxMapcontrol (FindExtensionByCLSID in ArcEngine Application)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, arcgis-engine, extensions

I have a small problem. I have begun rewriting code to work with an AxMapControl. Now at first this seemed to work and I was able to get a lot of code converted and working with the AxMapControl, but then I got to the GeoCoding part. I can't seem to figure out what to replace IApplication with to get the FindExtensionByCLSID function like below . . .

```
pApplication.FindExtensionByCLSID(pUID) as ILocatorExtension
```

but `IApplication` isn't available in ArcGIS Engine. How I can get Extension

Answer (score 3):

ArcEngine doesn't work like ArcGIS Desktop. If you have the proper licensing for a functionality or extension (e.g. spatial analyst) in ArcEngine, then you can use the related Interfaces of that extension.

ILocatorExtension, itself is dedicated to ArcGIS Desktop and can not be used with ArcEngine.

With ArcEngine your should utilize :

- ILocatorWorkspace2 Interface
- ILocatorManager Interface
- IDatabaseLocatorWorkspace Interface
- other related interfaces

Take a look at [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/SampleZips/253cc4ce-caf9-4e6c-b7c8-cd18fc3f458e.zip) sample application